# Applying memoization to the coin changing problem

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

I'm trying to solve the following problem (from [CodeRust 3.0](https://www.educative.io/collection/5642554087309312/5679846214598656)):

[image]

I thought I'd make use of the following recursive relation: in this example, the number of ways to make 7 with denominations `(1, 2, 5)` is the sum of the number of ways to make `0, 1, ..., 7` with denominations `(2, 5)` (that is, one recursive call on a smaller set of denominations for each choice of the number of the first coin, `1`).

In order to apply memoization, I thought I'd use [`functools.lru_cache()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache). Here is my solution so far (including `pytest` unit tests):

```
import pytest
import functools


@functools.lru_cache()
def solve_coin_change_dp(denominations, amount):
    if amount == 0:
        return 1
    if amount < 0:
        return 0
    if not denominations:
        return 0

    return sum(
        solve_coin_change_dp(
            denominations[1:],
            amount - i * denominations[0])
        for i in range(amount // denominations[0] + 1))


@pytest.fixture
def denominations():
    return (1, 2, 5)


def test_trivial():
    assert solve_coin_change_dp((1,), 1) == 1


def test_1(denominations):
    assert solve_coin_change_dp(denominations, 1) == 1


def test_2(denominations):
    assert solve_coin_change_dp(denominations, 2) == 2


def test_3(denominations):
    assert solve_coin_change_dp(denominations, 3) == 2


def test_4(denominations):
    assert solve_coin_change_dp(denominations, 4) == 3


def test_5(denominations):
    assert solve_coin_change_dp(denominations, 5) == 4


def test_7(denominations):
    assert solve_coin_change_dp(denominations, 7) == 6


def test_big_amount(denominations):
    solve_coin_change_dp(denominations, 1000)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main([__file__, '--duration', '1'])
```

The problem is that the `lru_cache` does not seem to be helping at all to make the implementation fast. For an input of `1000`, the program still takes ~10s to run:

```
coin_changing.py ........                                                [100%]

=========================== slowest 1 test durations ===========================
10.31s call     coin_changing.py::test_big_amount
========================== 8 passed in 10.35 seconds ===========================
```

If I consider the function calls, however, I would expect there to be 'saving' due to the memoization. For example, a call with arguments `(1, 2, 5), 5`, would lead to `(2, 5), 5`, `(2, 5), 4`, `(2, 5), 3`, `(2, 5), 2`, `(2, 5), 1`, and `(2, 5), 0`. The first and third of these should in turn at some point both lead to `(5,), 3`, which point one of these could use the cached result.

In short, why is this application of memoization not working?

Comment: What's the unmemoized runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lru_cache` is an *LRU cache*. As in, it evicts the Least Recently Used element when the cache is full and a new element needs to be inserted. The default cache size is 128. Your memoized results are getting evicted.

Set `maxsize=None` to use an unbounded, non-LRU cache:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def ...
```

Comment: Good catch! This reduces the runtime to 0.13s for the `test_big_amount`.